# Xcode :How can I stop video in webview and still using webview

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview, ios7, uipagecontrol

if I use

```
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [subView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
    }
```

my Webview  can't worked

```
I try to do this
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;

    [subView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];


}
```

I just want to go next page with paging scrollview  and stop video on next page

this my code scrollview paging

```
book = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"page11",@"page12",@"page13",@"page14",@"page15", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [book count]; i++) {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.height * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(1024,768);
    subView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[book objectAtIndex:i] ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@""]];
    [subView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    subView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [scrollView setBounces:NO];
    [scrollView addSubview:subView];
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024 * [book count], 768);
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
```

Can I play video and stop on I next page?  //Please advice

sorry my English isn't well

Comment: did you try this? [self.webView loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for Advice. I try this is works for me

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;


    for(int i = 0; i < _pageAmount ; i++){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        [_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    currentPage = page;

    if (currentPage > 0 && currentPage < [book count]-1) {
        [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:currentPage-1]reload];//
        [[self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:currentPage+1]reload];

    }

    if(self.interfaceOrientation == 1 || self.interfaceOrientation == 2){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:page inSection:0];
        [_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load a blank page into the UIWebView to stop the audio:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")];
```

or

```
[self.webView  loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks,I try but not work with [self.webView  loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil]; and  [self.webView loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")]; too